# Splitting 1D array into 2D array with just a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a string that follows the pattern:

```
"course|radio-selected|party-size,course|radio-selected|party-size,..."
```

I'm looking to split and transpose the string vertically by `,` and then split horizontally by `|`.

After I'm looking to condense the cells to only show unique names, an average of the radio buttons selected, and the total number of people attending that course. But I can't figure out how to transpose over horizontally within the same formula.

my current formula is:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",'Copy of Website Submissions'!A2:A),","))
```

I tried turning it into an array then splitting again, but that only gives me the first entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that we can't see what you see, and we don't know what you know, unless you show/tell us.

That said, the best I can do is take a guess. Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT('Copy of Website Submissions'!A2:A,",")),"|"))`

The key here is the `FLATTEN` command, which forms a single column of all results formed after the first `SPLIT`.

If you wind up with any blank rows, add a `QUERY` wrap like this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT('Copy of Website Submissions'!A2:A,",")),"|"),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))`

If these don't work as you expect, I encourage you to share a link to a copy of your sheet with the permission set (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Edit."

Comment: I added the link. The formula you provided works, but there is a bunch of ``#VALUE!``s everywhere.

Comment: Awesome.. ***Splitting 1D array into 2D array with just a formula.*** I don't know if excel can do this. Filterxml does give us 1D array. But not sure if it can further split it. Thanks. This is great learning... @ChristianRudder I guess the question title should be changed accordingly as this can be referred later many times.

Comment: Christian, seeing your sheet, I simply changed the `Col1` to `Col2` as the null check in the `QUERY`, since Col2 and Col3 have nulls where Col1 had the `#VALUE!` errors. The reason for the errors is that not all of your strings before the `SPLIT`s were of uniform construction (i.e., some had comma-separated groupings while others did not).